# Simultaneous diagonalization of two Riemmanian metrics

Tags: riemannian-geometry, diagonalization, orthonormal

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $g,h$  two Riemannian metrics on $M.$ Can one find a local frame $(e_i)$ orthonormal with respect to $g$ such that $$ h(e_i,e_j)=0$$ $\forall i \neq j?$

Comment: Dumb question:  Is it always the case that this can be done at a single point?

Answer (score 3):

It's always possible to find such a frame at a single point, as a consequence of the [finite-dimensional spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) applied to the self-adjoint operator $A$ that satisfies $h(X,Y) = g(X,AY)$.  But it might not be possible to find a continuous local frame in a neighborhood of each point. Here's a simple counterexample: Let $g$ be the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$ and let $h$ be the metric 
$$ 
h  = (1+ x^2 - y^2) dx^2 + 4 x y\, dx\,dy + (1 + y^2 - x^2) dy^2.
$$
You can check that away from the origin, the following $g$-orthonormal frame diagonalizes $h$:
$$
e_1 = \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \quad
e_2 = \frac{(y,-x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.
$$
Because the self-adjoint operator associated to $h$ has distinct eigenvalues  on $\mathbb R^2\smallsetminus \{0\}$, this orthonormal frame is unique up to $\pm$ signs and reordering.  But it has no continuous extension to the origin.